# Jquery form: sendbutton may only appear when 2 conditions are fulfilled

Tags: jquery, forms, email, if-statement

I'm making a form with 2 fields: one for users to fill in their emailadress and the other is a messagefield.
My goal in this story here: I want to have a sendbutton to appear only when in the emailfield a @ and a . appears AND when there's something written in the messagefield.
The result with code here: 
the sendbutton appears when there's a @ and a . written in the emailfield, so that's ok... but it also appears when the messagefield is empty.
The code works when I only have one variable in the if-statement:

```
if(at != -1 && punt != -1) --> works;

if(message !="") --> works;
```

But when I combine the 2 in 1 If-statement, as written here below it doesn't work the way I want it to.
I assume I have to write my if-statement differently but I don't know how... somebody has a clue?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#email, .contactmessage").keyup(function(){

        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var message = document.getElementsByClassName("contactmessage").value;
        //var email = $("#email").val();

        var at = email.indexOf("@");
        var punt = email.indexOf(".");



        if(at != -1 && punt != -1 && message !="")      {
            $(".deel2").slideDown();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".deel2").slideUp();
        }
    });

    });
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements in a NodeList, which is like an array. You can't get its value, because it's not a single element. You need to index it or loop over them.

Comment: If there can only be one `contactmessage`, why are you using a class instead of an ID?

Comment: Because before I had more fields in the form with the same css-code, now in fact it wasn't useful anymore to use a class... nevertheless this did the trick using a class: var message = document.getElementsByClassName("contactmessage")[0].value;  thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

The [`.getElementsByClassName()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a (possibly empty) HTMLCollection of elements, and the collection doesn't have a `.value` property. So your `if` test with `message != ""` will always be true because `message` will always be `undefined`.

You can get the value of the first element in the collection like this:

```
   var message = document.getElementsByClassName("contactmessage")[0].value;
   // add an index to get the first element -----------------------^
```

Or since you're using jQuery anyway, you could try this:

```
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var message = $(".contactmessage").val();
```

(Or from the way you describe your message field there is only one, so you could give it an id instead of (or as well as) a class and select by id.)

Comment: great nnnnnn! this did it:  var message = document.getElementsByClassName("contactmessage")[0].value; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your condition like this

```
    if(at != -1 && punt != -1 && message !=="")
```

Java script equality is tricky.